# Glassfish cluster instance restart blocks with JMS resources

Tags: java, glassfish, message-queue

We have the following glassfish 3.1.2 cluster instalation
M1 : DAS + instance 1
M2 : instance 2

In the cluster configuration we have the default settings for the JMS:

- Using the default_JMS_host automatically created on cluster creation
- Tried both EMBEDDED and LOCAL JMS Service Type using master broker with the default_JMS_host in Java Message Service in the cluster configuration

We created the following JMS resources:

- JMS Connection Factory of type QueueConnectionFactory with the cluster as target (also tried target server, and both)
- JMS Destination Resource of type Queue with the cluster as target (also tried target server, and both)

After creation, if we deploy an application using that queue both producers and consumer works perfectly.

The problem is, if we restart the instance (even without the application using the queue deployed) the starting procedure blocks without any exception in instance server log nor in instance imq log.

(if we delete JMS Connection Factory and JMS Destination Resources the instance restarts without problem)

Any solution known? What am i missing here?